# How often do you need to create a real class hierarchy in your day to day programming?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

I create business applications with heavy database use. Most of the programming work is just to connect components to the database and modifying components to adapt to general interface behaviour. I mostly use Delphi with its rich VCL library, and generally buy components needed. I keep most of the business logic in the database. I rarely get the chance to build a nice class hierarchy from the bottom up as there really is no need. Anyone else have this experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is not totally language-agnostic;

Some languages like Java have a fairly limited set of language features available, meaning that subclassing is fairly often used because it's a convenient method for re-use, technical inheritance.

Closures and lambdas of C# make inheritance for technical reasons much less relevant. So normally inheritance is used for semantic reasons (like cat extends animal).

The last C# project I worked on, we more or less made all of the class hierarchies within a few  weeks. After that it was more or less over.

On my current java project we create new class hierarchies all of the time.

Other languages will have other features that similarly affect this composition (mixins come to mind)

Answer (score 4):

For me, occasionally a problem is clearer or easier with subclassing, but not often.

This also changes quite a bit in a given design as it's refactored.

My biggest problem is that programming courses and texts give so much weight to inheritance, hierarchies, and polymorphism through base classes (vs. interfaces or dynamic typing). This helps create legions of programmers that subclass everything and their mother.

Comment: mother extends progenitor - there, fixed it for you ;) Yes, great point about the of subclassing for its own sake problem out there.

Answer (score 1):

I put on my architecting/class design hat probably once or twice a month. It's probably the best hat I have and is the most fun to wear.

Depends what stage of the lifecycle your project is in though.

Answer (score 1):

When your tackling problem domains you are well familiar with and already have a common code base to work from, you often have no need to create a new class hierarchy. It's when you stumble upon problems you have no ready solutions for, that you start building your own.

It's also very dependant on the type of applications you develop. If your domain already has well accepted conventions and libraries to work from, there probably isn't any need to reinvent the wheel (other than personal / academic interests). Some areas have inherently less available resources to work with, and in those you'll find yourself building everything from scratch most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

A majority of applications, especially business applications, contains at least some kind of business logic in it.  I would contend that business should not be in the database, but should rather be in the application.  You can put referential integrity in the database as I think this is a good choice, but business logic should be only in the application.

By class hierarchy, I suppose you mean do you always have to end up with some inheritance in your object model, then the answer is no.  But chances are you can often find some common code, factor it out and create a base class to contain the common code.

If you agree with me on the point that business logic should not be in the database, but should be in the application, then I recommend you look into the MVC Design Pattern to guide your design.  You will find your design contain classes or objects.  Your VCLs will represent your View, and you can have your Model classes map directly to the database table, i.e. each member in the class in the model corresponds to a field in a database table (again, this is the norm but there will be exception, where this simplicity fails to apply).  Then you'll need a layer to handle the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) of the Model classes to the database tables.  You will end up with an "layered" application that is easier to maintain and enhance.

Comment: In Delphi we have had datamodules for the last 10 or so years. They represent the controller in the MVC model. MVC have been a natural way of doing things in Delphi. There is a lot of controversy putting BL in the DB. I like it that way and it makes it easier to create both a web and desktop version

Comment: The business logic should be in the database, but that means the database should be an OODB.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by hierarchy - inheritance or layering?

When object oriented languages first came out, inheritance was overused.  Complicated hierarchies were common.  Now, interfaces (as in Java and C#) provide a simpler way to get the benefit of polymorphism without the complications of inheritance.  I rarely use inheritance anymore.

Layering, however, is vital when creating a large application.  Layering prevents general low-level classes (like lists) from directly referencing specific high-level classes (like web browser windows).  As far as I know, there isn't a formal way to describe layering, but there are general guidelines (model-view-controller (MVC), separate GUI logic from business logic, separate data from presentation, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the types/phases of the projects you're working on. I happen to do that everyday because I'm working on database internals for a new database, creating related libraries/frameworks. I'd imagine doing that a lot less if I'm working within a mature framework using other people's libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The time that I find class hierarchies most beneficial is when the relationship between objects actually does match a true "is-a" relationship in the domain.

However if I can avoid large hierarchies I will due to the fact that they are often a little more tricky to map to relational databases and can really complicate your database designs. Since you say most of your applications make heavy use of databases this would be something to take into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing Infrastructure for our companys' product, so I'm writing a lot of code that will be used later by guys in other teams. So I end up writing lots of abstract classes, interfaces, hierarchies and so on. Mostly it's just a pattern of "default behaviour in an abstract/virtual class, which other programmers may override".

Very challenging, I must say.